# expressions in an appositive relation

Tags: relative-clauses

I'd like to know whether expressions in an appositive relation can
be switched around. Please consider the following examples:

> a. John bought a Northern Inuit dog, (which is) a breed with a wolf-like appearance.

> b. John bought a dog with a wolf-like appearance, (which is) a Northern Inuit dog.

> c. John bought a Northern Inuit dog, (which is) a wolf-like breed.

> d. John bought a wolf-like dog, (which is) a Northern Inuit (dog).

For present purposes, please assume that all Northern Inuit dogs resemble wolves, and not all wolf-like dogs are Northern Inuit dogs.

Presumably, a and c are fine. b and d don't work (for semantic reasons or otherwise). But someone told me sentence d is fine without "which is." Do you think so? If that's true, do you know why "which is" makes it sound bad?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112452/discussion-on-question-by-apollyon-expressions-in-an-appositive-relation).

Answer (score 2):

There are different meanings, and ambiguities. To paraphrase:

- **(a)** John bought a Northern Inuit dog. The *Northern Inuit* dog is a breed with a wolf-like appearance.
- **(b')** John bought a dog with a wolf-like appearance; what he actually chose was a *Northern Inuit* dog.

is the default reading, though there is ambiguity. Dropping the 'which is' is probably necessary here, and some might prefer a colon to a comma.

- **(c)** is a reasonably close paraphrase of (a). As with (a), the 'which is' is optional.
- **(d'')** John bought a wolf-like dog which is a *Northern Inuit* dog. =
- **(d'')** John bought a wolf-like dog – and it's a *Northern Inuit* dog.
- **(d)** John bought a wolf-like dog, which is a *Northern Inuit* dog. =
- **(d)** John bought a wolf-like dog; these are known as *Northern Inuit* dogs.
- **(d')** John bought a wolf-like dog, a *Northern Inuit* dog.

is ambiguous, but probably defaults to sense (b) rather than sense (d).